# SonarQube Code Coverage report for .Net Framework C# code

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have tried several thing based on the google search but did not get any success.
tried [this link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/#header-4) also.

what I am trying to achieve....
Update the code coverage on SonarQube report site.
It remains 0.0 % all the time. For all the test I got.
On the VS side, I could see the code coverage is greater than 70%.

What I am using....
SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.7.2
C# code
.Net Framework 4.7
Console application

How I execute...
using the below cmd for execution…

```
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"ProjectName" /d:sonar.login=abcdefgh
MSBuild.exe ProjectNameSolution.sln /t:Rebuild
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login=abcdefgh
```

also....

```
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"ProjectName" /d:sonar.login=abcdefgh /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=\\TestResults\\.trx /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=\**\TestResults\.Coveragexml
dotnet build --no-incremental
dotnet test --collect "Code Coverage"
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login=abcdefgh
```

but results remains the same.

not sure what I am missing.

kindly help.

Thanks.